# How can I use Backbone.js with ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, rest, backbone.js

I'm preparing to implement a Backbone.js UI (client-side MVC) within ASP.Net MVC 3+ web application (server-side MVC).

I've read plenty of Backbone tutorials, but none that illustrate how the technology may or may not be useful in an ASP.Net MVC scenario.

What strategy should I follow when combining these two pieces?

Answer (score 18):

To be fair, Backbone.js (client application) and MVC (server application) should have nothing in common. The only thing Backbone.js requires is a Restful Api. So what I would do is take a look at MVC 4's Web Api ([Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344078/ASP-NET-WebAPI-Getting-Started-with-MVC4-and-WebAP)). There are quite a few tutorials on the subject, but the one I listed gives quite a good overview.

Once you understand how to implement a Restful API, look at any tutorial on backbone.js that integrates with a server application. Just substitute your api with the tutorial's api and you should be in business. Read this [book](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals), it is priceless and contains brilliant examples on how to implement a backbone.js application locally and with a server.

On a side note, MVC 4's Web API integrates perfectly with backbone. Have a look at a plugin developed by Addy Osmani, [Backbone.Paginator](http://addyosmani.com/blog/backbone-paginator-new-pagination-components-for-backbone-js/). It helps make filtering, pagination, skip, sort etc extremely easy with MVC 4's Web API and odata filters.

Comment: If you are going to downvote my answer, at least comment as to why you think it is not applicable.

Comment: +1 from me. I think thus is a good answer. I've been using both mvc and knockout on a few sample apps and agree that really all that is needed on the server side is a true rest api. But one thing I would like to see more information on is how to organise, load and compile view templates, maybe this is something MVC can help with, maybe using partial views?

Comment: Thank you very much. I also had the same problem. All my view templates were causing a mess in my application. I currently use this method [link](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals/tree/master/practicals/modular-todo-app). Still require nothing from MVC besides a REST api, and my view templates are only loaded when needed. Require.js, I believe, is the way to go and helps keep your app modular.

Answer (score 5):

After learning Backbone.js and using it on a few projects, I've found that most of my time is spent figuring out how to use it, and not what my backend is doing.  In terms of ASPMVC, you setup a few controller actions that return JSON.

Rob Connery uses Backbone.js with MVC3 in his series [Real-World ASP.NET MVC3](http://tekpub.com/productions/mvc3) on Tekpub.

Episode 6 - BackboneJS - is spent entirely introducing you to backbone and ASPMVC3 integration.  Unfortunately, you must purchase the entire series for $32 and it helps to watch the whole thing to get a sense for whats being built.  Further, I don't agree with the way he approaches everything in the videos but his use and description of Backbone.js is very helpful if you are new.

DocumentCloud (the project from which Backbone.js emerged) maintains a page entitled [Tutorials, blog posts and example sites](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Tutorials,-blog-posts-and-example-sites). They don't always list the backends used so you may have to browse all the links to see if you find anything.

[This is quick little tutorial](http://www.codethinked.com/building-epic-win-with-backbone-js) from real-world experience, basically wiring a backbone application to some ASPMVC endpoints.

Finally, [here is a recent post](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2012/02/17/integrating-backbone-js-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx) on Microsoft's own ASP.NET Weblogs called "Integrating Backbone.js with ASP.NET Web API".